# What is 'firmware linkage'?

Tags: drivers, toshiba-laptop

I have a Toshiba notebook, and there were missed driver, which I have fixed. It called Toshiba firmware linkage driver. I am interested, what is firmware linkage, and does it affect computer performance? I will be thankful to everyone for an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Source [The dreaded TOS1901 missing device on Toshiba Laptops (Fixed)](http://techforcommoners.blogspot.com.au/search?q=Firmware+Linkage+Driver)

> Since Windows Vista 64-Bit was introduced, many Toshiba laptop owners have been left with a single Unknown Device in Device Manager. This device is the Firmware Linkage Driver. While this device does not appear to affect system performance; it is annoying to have one Unknown Device in your Control Panel. The Firmware Linkage Driver  has the Hardware ID’s of TOS1901, *TOS1901 and ACPI/TOS1901.
>
> **Eventually, it was discovered that this particular device was installed as a part of the Toshiba Supervisor Password Utility**. This SHOULD have resulted in a simple fix but Toshiba made this utility locked to a specific set of Serial Numbers.* This meant that if your laptop had a serial number that wasn’t in this set, you were out of luck. The program would refuse to install and the driver would not load. I tried to get an image of this, but not that I have the Firmware Linkage Driver installed, I can't seem to get it to bring up an error.